# JavaScript - Test On Communication With More Than One Entity

Tags: javascript, testing

My micro-service A has this behavior: when it receives a message from service C it returns 200, does some calculations, and sends a new http request to service B.

I want to test A by mocking the request from C, and mock B to listen the request from A.
The problem here is that simple asyncronous approach is not enough here, since the relevant output from A is sent to another entity (i.e. not as response to C).

I thought to do that by sending the request from C and setting timeout to check if something has arrived to B meantime, but it's not very elegant.
Is there any way do that via test framework? (Prefer Mocha)

Answer (score 0):

suggest try use callbacks or Promise - "Testing asynchronous code with Mocha could not be simpler! Simply invoke the callback when your test is complete. By adding a callback (usually named done) to it(), Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test. This callback accepts both an Error instance (or subclass thereof) or a falsy value; anything else will cause a failed test."

see this topics https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code and https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises